# How do I add files on a shared server to Git when the solution is on my local machine?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

We have a number of websites and I have been directed to move them all from TFS into Git for source control.  I am having trouble getting this to work due to the way the code files are organized.

There is a solution file on each developer's local machine.  All of the files in the solution are on a webserver, called WEBDEV.  Those files are checked out exclusively (using TFS) and checked in by whoever is working on them.  Then the changed files are copied to WEBPRD, the production web server, when ready.  We use a very old CMS named Ektron, which requires thousands of files to be in the solution, and make it prohibitive to put  on each person's machine.  Also, the normal deployment mechanism or debugging in Visual Studio can't be used, so there's no point to making copies on my local machine.

Anyway, now that I have tried adding my solution to Git, I get a notification that files are outside of the solution folder and will not be tracked.  I have tried adding copies of the files I want to track locally, but that doesn't help because the files need to be on the web server and it's going to be a pain to have to constantly copy them over.  I have tried adding a solution file to the directory on the web server, but when I try to add a file manually using the command line Git throws a fatal error that says the file cannot be added because it already exists.  I also tried uploading the files using the Git UI, but the same error occurs when I make a change to a file and try to Push.  I have tried Pulling files after uploading them, and I get an error that another git process is running, though I am the only one doing anything with the files right now.

Is there a way to make a local repo in Git that includes both a solution file on my local machine and code files that are on a server and not in the same folder as the solution?  And hopefully not something that requires a command line entry for each file, because there are hundreds I want to track, and thousands more that need to be included in the solution though it's okay if they are not under source control.

Comment: Git knows nothing about "solutions". Git deals in commits, which in turn hold files; the files *must* be under some top level folder, which determines what their names will be. Git's names internally always use forward slashes and don't quite distinguish "folders", so you just have files named `path/to/file`. The act of *extracting* a commit (which holds a permanent read-only archive of *all* files) simply populates your *working tree* with files; Git will create folder `path` and then folder `to` inside `path` and then `file` within `to`, as needed, so that you get `path\to\file`.

Comment: The key point here, in any case, is that for *this repository*, all the *files* in *every commit* are in this set of folders-and-subfolders. There's no way to store `c:\other` *unless* the repository covers the entire ``c:\`` as its working tree (and that's a very bad idea! don't do that).

Comment: Because everything is *relative*, *you get to choose* where the extraction happens: you extract the commit (or use `git archive` to turn a commit into a tar or zip archive that you can extract elsewhere), and then *you choose* where it lands. The files will have paths based on the paths Git saved.

Comment: In any case, *every clone of a Git repository* contains *every commit*, and *every commit contains every file*. There's no "one file on machine A, another on machine B". The repository holds everything. That's what it means in Git when someone says "everything is local".